# How to write a script to run multi-processes in multi-core machine effectively

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, multicore

everyone. I have a file Python (for example named: run.py). This program takes some parameters (python run.py param1 param2 ...) and each tuple parameter is a setting. Now, I have to run many settings simultaneously to finish all as soon as possible. I wrote a file run.sh as follow:

```
python run.py setting1 &
python run.py setting2 &
#more setting
...
wait
```

This file will execute all processes simultaneously, right? And I run on the machine 64 core cpu. I have some question here:

1. Will each process run on one core or not?
2. If not, how can I do this?
3. If I can run a process per a core, time running of setting1 will equal to time running when I just run an individual process:   python run.py setting1

Comment: Look at **GNU Parallel**. You can control how many processes run at once easily and also generate permutations of arguments. Search on StackOverflow for `[gnu-parallel]` and click `newest`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html) module?

Assuming you want to execute some function `work(arg1, arg2)`  multiple times in parallel, you'd end up with something like this

```
import multiprocessing
p = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()
results = p.starmap(work, [(arg11, arg12), (arg21, arg22)....]
# do something with the list of results
```

If your functions all look very different from each other then you can get away by writing a function wrapper, like so:

```
def wrapper(dict_args, inner_function):
  return inner_function(dict_args)
# then launch the multiprocessing mapping

p.starmap(wrapper, [({'arg1': v1, 'arg2': v2}, job1), ({'foo': bar}, job2)..]
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try. But as you know, I not only just run on one file, but also on many files independently. for example file run1.py for job 1, run2.py for job 2...